# Отладка js в phpstorm в реальном времени

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, отладка

Можно ли в phpstorm настроить отладку js в режиме реального времени?
Хочу чтобы результат выполнения скриптов был виден в консоли IDE, а не браузера.

К примеру такие методы как console.log хочу видеть в самой IDE. И можно ли отладку перезапускать по сохранению файла, так сказать livereload отладка?

Comment: не очень поняла, честно говоря. Выводы в консоль, вроде console.log, и так показываются в консоли IDE, когда вы запускаете отладчик. А вот веб странички IDE отображать не умеет, встроенного браузера в ней нет.

Comment: Live reload как автоматический перезапуск отладчика отсутствует, зато есть Live edit - при редактировании в процессе отладки изменения в HTML, CSS и JS коде сразу отображаются в браузере, без перезагрузкию См. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/live-editing.html

Answer (score 1):

Надо установить в Chrome или Yandex-браузере [плагин](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji) "JetBrains IDE Support"

После чего выбрать на своей странице с javascript пункт "Inspect in Phpstorm". В самой IDE поставить точки останова в коде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если js собирается с webpack или другими транспилерами, то бандл надо собирать с созданием source maps

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]